# View created from Java code is wrapped in another view. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

1) Why, when I create my custom compound view from Java code it is wrapped in another view which creates another level of view hierarchy? If I use the `<include>` tag in the XML to create the view, this does not happened. (see the attached image from hierarchy manager). Any reason for that?

[image]

2) The image shows (the part where the view is created by `<include>` tag) another interesting behavior – that it is easily possible to have the views with the same `android:id` on the same hierarchy level. When the `findByViewId()` method is used then, the first view reference is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any reason for that?

Because that's the way you wrote the code If you do not want that behavior, fix your code.

> that it is easily possible to have the views with the same android:id on the same hierarchy level

Of course. You see this all the time with subclasses of `AdapterView`, such as `ListView`.

Comment: Hi you wrote _Because that's the way you wrote the code If you do not want that behavior, fix your code._ Easy to be said - but how? What is the difference between use of **<include>** XML element and inflating the same XML in Java code? Should I post source code? Thanks!

Comment: @STeN: "What is the difference between use of <include> XML element and inflating the same XML in Java code?" -- there is no immediate difference. The difference comes in what you do with the results. If I had to guess, in the latter case, you are having a `RoomInfoView` inflate a `RoomInfoView` and add it to itself, which would explain the duplicate levels. How you're avoiding the infinite recursion problem, though, is beyond me. :-)